# How do you iterate and apply logic to rows in DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

So I am trying to add a timer into a new column "Duration" that subtracts the time started, which is a `date time`, and displays how long it has been active. So far this is what I have:

XAML:

```
<DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding BlockName}" Header="Block" Width="200"/>
<DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Auditor}" Header="Auditor" Width="200"/>
<DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding AcctAuditor}" Header="Accounting Auditor" Width="200"/>
<DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding BlockLeader}" Header="Block Leader" Width="200"/>
<DataGridTextColumn x:Name="TimeStarted" Binding="{Binding TimeStarted}" Header="Started" Width="200"/>
<DataGridTextColumn x:Name="Duration" Header="Elapsed Time" Width="200"/>
```

Code Behind:

```
System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer dispatcherTimer = new System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer();
dispatcherTimer.Tick += dispatcherTimer_Tick;
dispatcherTimer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1);
dispatcherTimer.Start();

private void dispatcherTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (DataRowView dr in BlockStatus.ItemsSource)
        {
        var diff = dr.Row.Field<DateTime>("TimeStarted").Subtract(DateTime.Now);
        if (diff.TotalSeconds > 0)
        {
            dr.Row["Duration"] = string.Format("{0} d {1:D2}:{2:D2}:{3:D2}", diff.Days, diff.Hours, diff.Minutes, diff.Seconds);
        }
        else
        {
            dr.Row["Duration"] = "0 d 00:00:00";
        }
    }
}
```

I am trying to have a column that will count up in mm:ss in a new column based on another column.

Here is a picture:

[image]

This was solved using dispatch timer.

Comment: DateTime.Now is likely larger than TimeStarted. diff will be negative. anyway: what is the problem statement?

Comment: I am getting specified cast is not valid. when I run this.

Comment: `dr.Row.Field<DateTime>("TimeStarted")` - does TimeStarted column have DateTime type (and DateTime values)? please double-check or show code for DataTable creation

Comment: you also need binding for Duration column: `<DataGridTextColumn x:Name="Duration" Binding="{Binding Duration}"`

Comment: So I changed in SQL for it to be datetime, that fixed the issue with cast not being valid but then it raised this error: ": 'Column 'Duration' does not belong to table .'" I am populating from SQL database and duration is suppose to be a add on column.

Comment: @ASh any suggestions you can give me?

Comment: I don't see clear problem statement or [mcve]

Comment: @ASh I need to subtract datetime.now from timestarted column instead of this way: TimeSpan diff = dr.Row.Field<DateTime>("TimeStarted").Subtract(DateTime.Now); but I cannot figure out how it's done.

Comment: I have accomplished this thank you.